# What exactly are "indicators" (in the context of supplements) according to CGEL?

Tags: adverbs, adverbials, adjuncts

In CGEL, in the section on "supplements", there is a short subsection on "indicators" (pages 1354 and 1355).  These are defined as follows:  "Supplements may contain indicators which serve to clarify the nature of their semantic relation to the anchor."  Four examples are given and the function is said to be a "specifying" one.  It is not made explicit whether this is the only function or just one of many.  The examples given are "namely", "that is", "for example" and "especially".  Semantically, all represent an includer/included function (X namely Y, X for example Y and X particularly Y) and are best exemplified with appositives (specifying noun phrases):

*The interviewee, **namely** Jane, is here.*

But one can say that another includer/included function is a general X including Y:

*Everyone, **even** Jane, is here.*

Is "even" an indicator?  If it is, what about other degree adverbs, with other types of supplements:

*Jane left the room, **practically** running out.*

Is "practically" an indicator?  Or, if a focusing adverb like "especially" is an indicator, what about a modality adverb like "probably" (here with another type of supplement):

*Jane, **probably** angry at the fact, left the room.*

Or, going back to what I presume is a specifying noun phrase:

*Someone, **probably** Jane, is here.*

To sum, the question is:  Could any adverb beginning a supplement be considered an indicator?  If not, then what is an indicator in more precise terms?

Comment: If it meets the criteria specified in CGEL, then yes.

Comment: What is CGEL? Something for the piles? I don't find it in my dictionary.

Comment: "Serve to clarify the nature of their semantic relation" is not a criterion, but a fond hope. None of the terms are defined syntactically, so anything could fit. As we would say it here, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @David: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. A huge and recent grammar (which I want, but cannot afford).

Comment: "namely" and "that is" specify or respecify; "for example" exemplifies and "especially" highlights.

Answer (score 0):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) defines "indicators" as follows:

> Supplements may contain **indicators** which serve to clarify the nature of their semantic relation to the anchor.

I think that all the examples in CGEL are in line with the definition, perhaps except for [13vi]

> vi *She was highly critical of both proposals,* [***especially** the second one*].

Here, *the second one* alone cannot be a supplement:
**She was highly critical of both proposals,* [*the second one*].

I doubt, therefore, that ***especially*** serves to clarify the nature of the semantic relation between the supplement *the second one* and the anchor *both proposals*. Rather, it's necessary for *the second one* to be a legitimate supplement.

No other examples of **indicators** presented in CGEL are necessary for the supplement to be a legitimate one. That is, you can omit them without changing their meaning or function.

If ***especially*** in [13vi] were a correct example of **indicators**, the boldfaced words in your own examples should be considered to be **indicators**. But since that doesn't seem to be the case, I think they're not **indicators**.

Among your examples, two don't work without the boldfaced words:

**Everyone, Jane, is here.*

**Someone, Jane, is here.*

The other three do work without them, but their meaning is different from the original:

*The interviewee, Jane, is here.*

*Jane left the room, running out.*

*Jane, angry at the fact, left the room.*

This I take to mean that these boldfaced words do not merely clarify the nature of the semantic relation between the supplement and the anchor, but that they are necessary parts of the supplements.

Comment: Many thanks for the thoughtful reply.  Unfortunately, I don't buy it.  First, you're not giving CGEL the benefit of the doubt, by proposing that they got "especially" wrong.  Second, if "especially" is wrong, then "for example" should be wrong too.  "Especially" and "for example" are semantically similar; "for example" implies an example while "especially" implies the most significant example.  Also, in "I like fruit, for example apples", "for example" is not deletable.

Comment: I think the reason "especially" is not deletable in the quoted example is that it's used with a noun phrase.  Many of the other examples are used with full clauses, which of course can stand on their own.  Lastly, in the last example in the subsection, to demonstrate an indicator can be in a non-initial position, "for example" can be replaced with "especially", and "especially" would be deletable:  "The therapist’s level tone is bland and neutral – [he has, for example, avoided stressing ‘you’]."

Comment: Any grammatical terms can be defined narrowly or broadly, depending on how you want them to be. As I understand it, CGEL has defined the term rather narrowly, but some of their examples seem to go outside of their own definition, which I have pointed out to answer your question. But you seem to suggest that we should interpret their definition more broadly, which is fine with me. But then, what's the point of your asking the question?

Comment: One point of the question is this:  if adverbs/adjuncts in noun phrase supplements are not all indicators, what are they?  That is, how is an adverb being part of a noun phrase explained?  Is the adverb modifying the noun?  Should they not be thought of as adverbs, but something else?  If so, what?  Connectors?

Comment: They are adverbs. What else should they be? Adverbs can be part of an NP, if you didn't know that already.

Comment: My understanding is that adverbs do not modify nouns (although they can be external modifiers to noun phrases).  If I am mistaken, please enlighten me.  If "probably Jane" can be a noun phrase in "someone, probably Jane, is here", why can't it be a noun phrase anywhere else ("I saw probably Jane", "he gave it to probably Jane", et cetera)?

Comment: You ask how we explain "an adverb being part of a noun phrase". And then you say they can be external modifiers to NPs. If you know the latter, why do you ask what you ask?

Comment: Let me try again.  "Someone, probably Jane, is here."  Are you saying "probably" is an adverb modifying the noun "Jane"?

Comment: Let me try again. I said, "Adverbs _can_ be part of an NP." Some can, others can't. Even the same adverb can or can't, depending on context. In _Someone will be here in probably 10 minutes_, _probably_ does combine with an NP _10 minutes_ to form a larger NP _probably 10 minutes_. But in _Someone, probably Jane, is here_, the same adverb doesn't seem to combine with an NP _Jane_ to form a larger NP _probably Jane_, for _I saw probably Jane_ doesn't work.

Comment: Does that mean the adverb in _Someone, probably Jane, is here_ has to be an indicator? Not unless it serves to clarify the nature of the semantic relation between _probably Jane_ and _someone_. So we're back to square one.

Comment: Sorry if I appear fatuous, but the question was "is probably is an adverb modifying the noun Jane?"  If the answer is yes, then there is a conflict with how CGEL defines an adverb.  (*Adverbs characteristically modify verbs and other categories except nouns*. P563.)  If the answer is no, then this is an alley we can go down.

Comment: Note _Jane_ can be both a noun and an NP.

Comment: I accept that, but CGEL make the distinction in this context and make it explicit that their definition of adverbs excludes single constituent nouns.  They give the following example, contrasting the two:  *"Almost the whole book", for example, has the NP the whole book as head, and may be contrasted with "She congratulated him on his [almost success]", where it is inadmissibly functioning as modifier of the noun success.*

Comment: CGEL can't be saying that an adverb cannot modify a single word NP. You can certainly say "Almost everyone speaks English".

Comment: It is possible that I'm misunderstanding what they say.  If you are able, I would be grateful if you could have a look and tell me how.  The paragraph in question, which I partly quoted above, is on pages 562 and 563 under "5.1 Adverbs as modifiers of heads that are not nouns".

Comment: You have drifted too far away from your original question. You might want to post another question for that.